# Composition and quality of mushroom spores

Tags: mycology

**Message to moderator(s):**
*This question was deleted since it looks similar to a question in [another SE](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/37268/can-mushroom-spores-survive-the-vacuum-and-radiation-of-space).
However, the question being asked in this SE is completely different. Would that be a strong enough basis to restore this post?*

---

From this [source](http://www.explorebigsky.com/are-mushrooms-from-outer-space), it states that:

> Living spores have been found and collected in every level of earth’s atmosphere. **Mushroom spores are electron-dense and can survive in the vacuum of space**. Additionally, their outer layer is **actually metallic and of a purple hue**, which naturally allows the spore to deflect ultraviolet light. And as if all this wasn’t unique enough, the **outer shell of the spore is the hardest organic compound to exist in nature**.

With regards to a mushroom spore's electron density, having an outer metallic / purple layer, and the hardness of its outer shell, have these things been confirmed in biological experiments?

Comment: Were there any references associated with these claims?  Where have you looked to see whether there is any credible support for these statements?

Comment: @tyersome No, there were no references in that article, I also heard similar claims in a podcast that predates that article. I have looked into general websites regarding mushroom spores (don't have access to peer-reviewed biology publications), and they don't seem to have any information with regards to the composition and quality of mushroom spores.

Comment: Please don't cross post to multiple SE sites.

Comment: This post is not substantially different from the other one. See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu - answers to both of these questions are going to touch on the same sorts of source, if the source even exists. Generally "is there support for this claim I found on the internet" questions are not acceptable here, either, without some additional research on your part.